# How to take a result on another page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

```
Image1.Visible = true;

Label2.Text = "Correct Ans       = " + answer.ToString();
Label3.Text = "Incorrect Ans     = " + wrong.ToString();
Label20.Text = "Total Questions  = " + count.ToString();
Label21.Text = "Score            = " + answer* 10;
Label26.Text = "Percentage       = " + Math.Round(answer / count* 100)+ " %";

answer = 0;
wrong = 0;
```

Comment: please elabotrate the question which result??

Comment: ... and what does your code not achieve, where does it already what you want to accomplish?

Comment: CSS tag is useless

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to achieve this.I would suggest you read [A Beginner's Tutorial on ASP.NET State Management](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331962/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management) and decide which one suits you best

Here's a simple example which uses three of these technologies, namely:

1. Query strings
2. Session state
3. Cookies

### Setting values:

```
string name = txtName.Text;

//1.Session
Session["name"] = name;

//2.Cookies
Response.Cookies["name"].Value = name;
Response.Cookies["name"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

//3.Query strings
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?name=" + name);
```

### Reading values:

```
//1.Session
string nameFromSession = Session["name"] as string;
//2.Cookies
string nameFromCookie = Request.Cookies["name"].Value;
//3.Query strings
string nameFromQueryString = Request.QueryString["name"];
```